# Sddm is not starting but in theory everything is working!

Tags: debian, kde, debian-installer, display-manager, sddm

It wasn't a long time ago when I decided to start an adventure with Linux. I started with a virtual machine (VMware workstation Pro) and everything worked fine. I've picked Debian 10.4.0 distro with KDE Plasma desktop. I was so pleased with the Debian that I installed it on my physical drive. Unfortunately, `sddm` isn't starting after selecting the Debian GNU/Linux option from the GNU GRUB menu.

I found a lot of solutions for not working sddm but none of them helped. 
This is what I have after booting Debian GNU/LINUX:

[image]

Few lines higher there was "Watchdog hardware is disabled".

The first thing I checked, is if the sddm is set to default display manager and it appealed to valid directory `/usr/bin/sddm`. Then I tried to enable it with `# systemctl enable sddm` but it shows this:

[image]

But when I typed `# systemctl status sddm` it prints that.

[image]

I don't know how to fix it. SDDM is not showing but it seems working. Lots of people have problems with a black screen but as you can see, not in that case. I reinstalled Debian with non-official non-free installation and it works better (it didn't detect my wifi card before). However, it still not working.

If it can be helpful, this is my PCs specification:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3800X
- GPU: MSI Geforce RTX 2070 Super Gaming X Trio
- MOTHERBOARD: MSI MPG X570 Gaming Edge wifi

Comment: This solution works for me [No GUI error after installing debian buster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63867477/no-gui-error-after-installing-debian-buster)

Answer (score 4):

`sddm.service` is started by symbolic link `/etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service` (which points to whichever X Display Manager you've installed and chosen to run as the default display manager), which is in turn called by `graphical.target`.

If `sddm` fails to start the GUI login screen/autologin session, you should look at `/var/lib/sddm/.local/share/sddm/xorg-session.log` and/or `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for clues.

It might be that you're missing the necessary `xserver-xorg-video-*` package: for Geforce RTX 2070, the open-source `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` can just about handle it, but you might get better results with the non-free `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia` (version 418.* or newer).

If using the `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`, you might need some firmware files with RTX 2070 - those come packaged in `firmware-misc-nonfree`.

If `startx` works, something might be wrong with the `sddm` state file `/var/lib/sddm/state.conf`, its configuration file `/etc/sddm.conf` and/or the default scripts located in `/usr/share/sddm/scripts` or their sysadmin-customizable versions in `/etc/sddm/`.

---

The nuts and bolts of Debian 10's `sddm` session: (assuming X11, not Wayland)

When `sddm` starts up, it starts the X server (`/usr/bin/X`), runs the `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup` script (which is empty by default), and then starts the `sddm-greeter` for the login prompt, unless autologin is configured in `sddm.conf`. If multiple session types are defined as `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/xsessions/`, the greeter will offer a choice of session types too, defaulting to whatever the user chose on previous GUI login. At this point, the session type selection only sets the `$STARTUP` environment variable to point at the command specified by the `.desktop` file.

Starting the actual user session happens via `/etc/sddm/Xsession`, which runs as the logging-in user, initializes the user's shell environment for the GUI session, then executes `/etc/X11/Xsession`, which should be invoked not just by `sddm` but by every method of starting a X session in Debian, including `startx`.

(With Wayland, the session script would be `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/wayland-session` instead, and I am not familiar with what would happen after that.)

`/etc/X11/Xsession` will check for the presence of various classic X session configuration files. Then it will source any scripts in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d`, which will, among other things, check that the session startup command chosen by the `sddm-greeter` actually exists, and fall back to sane (sysadmin-adjustable) defaults if not, and finally actually start it. For a KDE session, the session startup command will be `exec /usr/bin/startkde`.

Since `exec` is used, this command will take over the PID of the shell process that was running `/etc/X11/Xsession` and any scripts sourced by it before this point. This command will be the "linchpin" of the entire X login session: when this process ends, `sddm` will consider the session to be over, and will trigger the end of the entire GUI login session: the `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xstop` script will be executed, the X server will be reset, a new `xauth` cookie will be generated. Any remaining processes from the old session may receive a HUP signal at this point and will usually die off.

Comment: `echo 'exec /usr/bin/startplasma-x11' > ~/.xinitrc` worked to make `startx` start KDE on top of Ubuntu server. SDDM status is active, and used `dpkg-reconfigure sddm` however I still have blinking cursor on tty1 and tty7+. (This is inside KVM/virt-mgr, but shouldnt matter). `startx` starts Kubuntu DE, but still cant get to login screen by using logout. Am using `sddm --example-config > /etc/sddm.conf` for default config. I checked `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/sddm.log`.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/691378/cant-get-to-sddm-login-screen-startx-works-kde-on-ubuntu-server

Answer (score -1):

After trying many solutions, I found by myself an answer to the problem.
Since sddm didn't start automatically at boot, but

```
$ systemctl start sddm
```

worked fine after logging in as root, I tried to change from:

$ ls /etc/rc3.d/S03sddm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 apr  4  2020 /etc/rc3.d/S03sddm -> ../init.d/sddm

to:

$ ls /etc/rc3.d/S07sddm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 apr  4  2020 /etc/rc3.d/S07sddm -> ../init.d/sddm

simply renaming that, and it worked fine since next reboot!
I hope to have been useful for some people.