# No GUI error after installing debian buster

Tags: debian, display-manager, sddm

I have installed Debian 10 on my laptop Dell Inspiron . But when booting first time into Debian, It directs me into the command-line interface, why?

I am sure, I have chosen Graphical Install during installation.

Is it related to the graphics of my laptop? My laptop has **AMD Radeon R2** graphics and I am using the SDDM Display manager. It has **AMD APU Dual Core E1** processor.

I have installed **KDE plasma**, **LxDM**, and **Lxqt** in the select and install software step during installation.

I have chosen SDDM as my Display manager between **lightdm** and **sddm**.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution for this problem, I think the **sddm** display manager is not working fine and thats's why I am booting into CLI.
So, I just have to install another display manager which should work with my laptop hardware.

A brief explaination on this problem is here:
[Sddm is not starting but in theory everything is working!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586302/sddm-is-not-starting-but-in-theory-everything-is-working)

First step: Update the /etc/apt/sources.list

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add the following repositories(just copy and paste it):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main

# non-free firmwares
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
```

save the file by `Ctrl-O` and `Ctrl-M`. Close the file by using `Ctrl-X`.

run `sudo apt-get update`
and installed the lightdm display manager,you can install which you want

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Now we have to choose a display manager,so run the command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and choose the **lightdm** among the other options and **reboot** now. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to graphics-driver issues.
I experienced the same with fresh debian buster kde plasma. In contrast to you, I use nvidia.

To solve this I had to add *contrib* and *non-free* to my source.list:

```
nano /etc/apt/source.list

deb http://ftp.uni-mainz.de/debian/ buster main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.uni-mainz.de/debian/ buster main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main non-free contrib

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.uni-mainz.de/debian/ buster-updates main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.uni-mainz.de/debian/ buster-updates main non-free contrib
```

The next thing was to update and install the linux firmware package:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firmware-linux
sudo reboot
```

Right after this procedure I was able to launch kde plasma.

---

Unfortunately my desktop freezed several times with the stock kernel driver. After having installed the proprietary nvidia drivers, these issues went away. `sudo apt install -y nvidia-detect && sudo nvidia-detect`. Than install whatever driver *nvidia-detect* recommends to you or just do `sudo apt install nvidia-driver`

Tested with GeForce GT 710 and gtx970

Comment: you make this process very easy. Thank for your solution